# Load form fields related to the ID from add button PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I want to display form input fields for users to fill in a div when the button is clicked, buttons are dynamically created from the database. The buttons are from checks table with the primary key checkId, and the checkfields have the foreign key checkId.

**Model:**

```
function fetchChecks(){
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from checks");
    return $query->result();
}

function getFields(){
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from checkfields");
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function addApplication() {     
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userid');
    $data['checks'] = $this->createUser->fetchChecks();
    $data['fields'] = $this->createUser->getFields();
    $this->load->view('clients/application', $data);        
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <?php 
            $k=0;
            foreach($checks as $chk)
            {
              $k++;
        ?>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addChecks" data-values='<?=json_encode($chk)?>' style="margin-bottom:20px; width:150px;" ><?php echo $chk->checkName; ?> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>

        <?php 
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

each id from button has a different set of input fields which I would like to load into a div if the button is clicked, I am stuck at making an ajax call as I am learning the same, please let me know how to do the same

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS OUT**

Why not use append?

```
    <script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="btn">Click me</button>
<span id="div"></span>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var field = '<input type="text" name="" placeholder="Field">';
        // for (var i = 1; i >= 0; i++) {
            $('#div').append(field);
        // }
    });
});
 </script>
```

Remember to add jquery link before the jquery code

Comment: I have used span tag as an example with an id [div], you can specify the div of choice by just adding the id="div".

Comment: I am able to get the value of the ID using var data = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-values')); and I need to pass it to an php variable to be able to use it